# Why does my UIButton's background layer animate in, and how can I stop it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, swift, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` subclass, and when I set the `hidden` property of the background layer it animates the alpha from 0 to 1. I want an instantaneous jump from 0 to 1. Why is it animating and how do I stop it from doing this?

Here's my code:

```
private var subLayer: CALayer!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    addTarget(self, action: "touchedDown", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    addTarget(self, action: "canceledTouch", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside | .TouchUpOutside | .TouchDragExit | .TouchCancel)
}

override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()

    // Add a background layer that is tight to the text in the button to indicate the button being pressed
    subLayer = CALayer()
    subLayer.frame = CGRectInset(bounds, -4.0, 5.0)
    subLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 204/255.0, green: 232/255.0, blue: 253/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    subLayer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    subLayer.hidden = true
    layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, atIndex: 0)
}

func touchedDown() {
    subLayer.hidden = false
}

func canceledTouch() {
    subLayer.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything done in Core Animation (that's the "CA" in "CALayer") will be animated unless you disable animation.

There are several ways to disable the default animations, but the only one that works in all situations is:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

subLayer.hidden = false

CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: +1 for beginning and committing a transaction. All other answers *may* cause unexpected issues by calling `setDisableActions` at a potentially undesired time on the containing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the automatic animation that layers have with `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`